# Swift - Given an Int like 30 how to take ranged numbers by 7?

Tags: swift, kotlin

Let's suppose I have an Int like 30, how can i take ranged numbers by 7 and put them into a list of pairs in Swift?

For example in this case it would be [(1, 7), (8, 14), (15, 21), (22, 28), (29, 30)] where the last couple is 29-30.

I found a code in Kotlin that may do that but I don't know how could it be in Swift since I don't know Kotlin. I post it in case it is helpful.

```
val myInt = 28
val list = (1..ceil(myInt/7.0).toInt()).mapIndexed { index, i ->
    7*index + 1 to (7*index + 7).coerceAtMost(myInt)
}

print(list)
```

Update:

I tried this code so far:

```
var days = 30
var daysInt: [Int] = []
var index = 0
      
        for i in 1...days {
                
                 if index <= days {
                    if i == 1 {
                        index += 1
                        daysInt.append(index)
                        index += 6
                        daysInt.append(index)
                    } else {
                        index += 1
                        daysInt.append(index)
                        index += 6
                        daysInt.append(index)
                    }
                }
            }
```

And the output is:

- 0 : 1

  - 1 : 7
  - 2 : 8
  - 3 : 14
  - 4 : 15
  - 5 : 21
  - 6 : 22
  - 7 : 28
  - 8 : 29
  - 9 : 35

All fine but the 35 should be 30.

I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: that kotlin code actually makes a list of pairs like `[(1, 7), (8, 14), (15, 21), (22, 28)]`, is that what you want, or just a list of ints?

Comment: Have a look at [stride(from:to:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stride(from:to:by:)) and [map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/map(_:))

Comment: btw a much shorter Kotlin implementation is `val list = (1..myInt).chunked(7).map { it.first() to it.last() }`

Comment: @k314159 do you know how could it be in Swift?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Swift.

Comment: Hello @Ivo, I updated the question: a pairs is fine.

Comment: Another Kotlin implementation is `(1..myInt step 7).map { it to min(it + 6, myInt) }`. Now use Martin's recommendation to look at the Swift methods `stride` and `map`.

Comment: Hello @MartinR, you're right. I updated the question with the code I tried. The best should to put it into a pairs rather than array of Int.

Comment: Might I suggest just literally using `let result = [(1, 7), (8, 14), (15, 21), (22, 28), (29, 30)]`? It's simpler and clearer.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your problem statement. "Let's suppose I have an Int like 30, how can i take ranged numbers by 7 and put them into a list of pairs in Swift?". It's only because you provide your desired output that we can make any sense of your question. You should edit your question to provide a clear definition of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kotlin code

```
(1..myInt step 7).map { it to min(it + 6, myInt) }
```

which was suggested in a comment can almost literally be translated to Swift.

With [`stride()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stride(from:to:by:)) you can create the sequence  1, 8, 15, ..., 29, and with [`map()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/map(_:)) you can map each value to a tuple:

```
let days = 30
let list = stride(from: 1, to: days, by: 7).map { ($0, min($0+6, days)) }
print(list)
// [(1, 7), (8, 14), (15, 21), (22, 28), (29, 30)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost similar apprach

```swift
import Foundation
let numbers = 1...7
let myInt = 28
let indexAndNum = numbers.enumerated().map { (index, element) in
    return (((7*index)+1) ,((7*index)+7))
}
print(indexAndNum.filter { $0.0 <=  myInt})
```

###### Update

```swift
import Foundation
let numbers = 1...7
let myInt = 30
let indexAndNum = numbers.enumerated().map { (index, element) in
    return (((7*index)+1) ,((7*index)+7))
}
let f: [(Int,Int)] = indexAndNum.filter { $0.0 <=  myInt }
print(f.map { 
    if $0.1 < myInt { return ($0.0,$0.1) } else {return ($0.0,myInt)}
 
 } as [(Int,Int)]
 )
```

Comment: if myInt is 30. This will not work. Please re check

Comment: Thanks @udi for the info I have updated it